# Xml Custom Element With Soap12 tag

Tags: c#, xml, soap

The following code will create  instead of , how to force it to become `<soap12:Body>` tag.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode docNode = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlNode envelopeNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("soap12", "Envelope", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
xmlDoc.DocumentElement?.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlDoc.DocumentElement?.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

XmlNode bodyNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "soap12", "Body", null);       
envelopeNode.AppendChild(bodyNode);

xmlDoc.AppendChild(envelopeNode);
```

will result in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <Body />
</soap12:Envelope>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication55
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                "</soap12:Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);

            XElement envelope = doc.Root;
            XNamespace nsSoap12 = envelope.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("soap12");

            XElement body = new XElement(nsSoap12 + "Body");
            envelope.Add(body);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct namespace to `CreateNode`:

```
XmlNode bodyNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, 
    "soap12", "Body", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
```

Although this whole problem is far simpler using the more modern LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";

var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(ns + "Envelope",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap12", ns),
        new XElement(ns + "Body")
    )
);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J99wp6) for a working demo.

Comment: if wanted to format something as follow? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns:soap12="w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">; <soap12:Body> <Model xmlns="wservice/">; <name>Andrea</name> <age>23</age> </Model> </soap12:Body> </soap12:Envelope>